# SQL Server Trigger logic no longer bypassing foreign key checks until the trigger is complete

Tags: sql, sql-server, triggers, foreign-keys, cascade

Here's a simplified example of what I have implemented many times before but is not working now.

I have an SQL Server table called tblCompany with 2 foreign keys to the same table - tblEmployee.

Foreign Key 1 = tblCompany.Name + tblCompany.SystemAdminName = tblEmployee.CompanyName + tblEmployee.Name

Foreign Key 2 = tblCompany.Name + tblCompany.LocationAdminName = tblEmployee.CompanyName + tblEmployee.Name

When I introduce these foreign keys and set both to cascade updates and/or deletes I get the following error.

Introducing FOREIGN KEY constraint 'FK_tblEmployee_tblCompany1' on table 'tblEmployee' may cause cycles or multiple cascade paths. Specify ON DELETE NO ACTION or ON UPDATE NO ACTION, or modify other FOREIGN KEY constraints.

The solution is to set one of the foreign keys not to cascade deletes or updates and create a trigger to do this instead.

The triggers look something like this

```
CREATE TRIGGER dbo.trgrEmployeeUpd
ON dbo.tblEmployee
AFTER UPDATE
BEGIN

IF UPDATE(Name)
UPDATE c
SET c.LocationAdminName = i.Name
FROM tblCompany c
JOIN DELETED d ON d.CompanyName = c.Name AND d.Name = c.LocationAdminName
JOIN INSERTED i ON i.SurrogateKey = d.SurrogateKey

END
```

On SQL Server 2008 R2 Express this worked by temporarily ignoring the referential integrity of the two tables until the update and trigger are complete. I am now on SQL Server 2012 Web and I am getting a referential integrity error occurring.

**EDIT**

Just in-case anyone can find a better solution than handling the referential integrity myself here's the real tables missing most of the fields isolated in the SQL below with the error message.

```
USE Test
GO
/****** Object:  Table [dbo].[tblClientPlace]    Script Date: 16/06/2014 12:47:41 ******/

CREATE TABLE [dbo].[tblClientPlace](
[CompanyName] [varchar](50) NOT NULL,
[LocationName] [varchar](30) NOT NULL,
[Name] [varchar](20) NOT NULL,
[SurrogateKey] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
 CONSTRAINT [PK_tblPersonPlace] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
[CompanyName] ASC,
[LocationName] ASC,
[Name] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]

GO

CREATE TABLE [dbo].[tblAttendanceClientPlaceMapping](
[CompanyName] [varchar](50) NOT NULL,
[WorkingLocationName] [varchar](30) NOT NULL,
[WorkingClientPlaceName] [varchar](20) NOT NULL,
[AttendanceLocationName] [varchar](30) NOT NULL,
[AttendanceClientPlaceName] [varchar](20) NOT NULL,
CONSTRAINT [PK_tblAttendanceClientPlaceMapping] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
[CompanyName] ASC,
[WorkingLocationName] ASC,
[WorkingClientPlaceName] ASC,
[AttendanceLocationName] ASC,
[AttendanceClientPlaceName] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]

GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[tblAttendanceClientPlaceMapping]  WITH CHECK ADD  CONSTRAINT [FK_tblAttendanceClientPlaceMapping_tblClientPlace] FOREIGN KEY([CompanyName], [WorkingLocationName], [WorkingClientPlaceName])
REFERENCES [dbo].[tblClientPlace] ([CompanyName], [LocationName], [Name])
ON UPDATE CASCADE
ON DELETE CASCADE
GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[tblAttendanceClientPlaceMapping] CHECK CONSTRAINT [FK_tblAttendanceClientPlaceMapping_tblClientPlace]
GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[tblAttendanceClientPlaceMapping]  WITH CHECK ADD  CONSTRAINT [FK_tblAttendanceClientPlaceMapping_tblClientPlace1] FOREIGN KEY([CompanyName], [AttendanceLocationName], [AttendanceClientPlaceName])
REFERENCES [dbo].[tblClientPlace] ([CompanyName], [LocationName], [Name])
GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[tblAttendanceClientPlaceMapping] CHECK CONSTRAINT [FK_tblAttendanceClientPlaceMapping_tblClientPlace1]
GO

CREATE TRIGGER [dbo].[trgrClientPlaceUpd] 
ON  [dbo].[tblClientPlace] 
AFTER UPDATE
AS 
BEGIN
-- SET NOCOUNT ON added to prevent extra result sets from
-- interfering with SELECT statements.
SET NOCOUNT ON;

IF UPDATE(Name) OR UPDATE(LocationName)
BEGIN 
UPDATE acpm 
SET AttendanceLocationName = i.LocationName, AttendanceClientPlaceName = i.Name
FROM tblAttendanceClientPlaceMapping acpm
JOIN DELETED d ON d.CompanyName = acpm.CompanyName AND d.LocationName = acpm.AttendanceLocationName AND d.Name = acpm.AttendanceClientPlaceName
JOIN INSERTED i ON i.SurrogateKey = d.SurrogateKey
END

END
GO

INSERT INTO tblClientPlace (CompanyName,LocationName,Name)
VALUES('Hill Valley Cleaners','Hill Valley','Biff Tannen')

INSERT INTO tblClientPlace (CompanyName,LocationName,Name)
VALUES('Hill Valley Cleaners','Hill Valley','Griff Tannen')

INSERT INTO tblAttendanceClientPlaceMapping (CompanyName,WorkingLocationName, WorkingClientPlaceName,AttendanceLocationName,AttendanceClientPlaceName)
VALUES('Hill Valley Cleaners','Hill Valley','Biff Tannen', 'Hill Valley','Griff Tannen')

UPDATE tblClientPlace SET Name = 'Mad Dog Tannen' WHERE CompanyName = 'Hill Valley Cleaners' AND LocationName = 'Hill Valley' AND Name = 'Griff Tannen'
```

Results in error Msg 547, Level 16, State 0, Line 1
The UPDATE statement conflicted with the REFERENCE constraint "FK_tblAttendanceClientPlaceMapping_tblClientPlace1". The conflict occurred in database "Test", table "dbo.tblAttendanceClientPlaceMapping".
The statement has been terminated.

Comment: I have done some more testing and it seems that this method does work in another database on the same server so it's nothing to do with the version of SQL Server.

Comment: 1. Get some tble etc declaration code to give you the error in isolation then cut and paste the code and error into the question. 2. The odds that a table with PK company should have a FK to its employees table are about zero. (Vs a table about officers with company and employee FKs.)

Comment: Correction... This method does not work elsewhere either. In the end I had to manage the referential integrity myself. Thanks philipxy for your comment... the example I gave was simplified but I do have a foreign key to the company system admin in the company table... the reference to the location admin is elsewhere. The real issue is with some other tables I just wanted to simplify it.

Comment: @philipxy I have just added the real tables isolated as you suggested. See above.